# Remove "Recent files" from My Files app in Samsung Galaxy Core Prime

Tags: samsung-galaxy-core-prime, my-files

As you can see the "Recent files" in the picture, it's really annoying - it remembers every image which I just opened, thus violating my privacy.

**Note** that "Recent files" even remembers and shows my hidden images (which Images or Gallery won't scan and show).

I can make the "Recent files" forget about my recent images by going to **Settings -> Application manager -> All -> My Files -> Clear data** (check the second image), but that's just exhausted.

Is there anyway to completely remove this annoying "Recent files"?

In the past, I used Samsung Galaxy V and it doesn't have this  "Recent files", then why my Samsung Galaxy Core Prime has?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Recent files]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Ugh, no but you can use other file explorers like es explorer, it doesn't has recent file.

Comment: How is it violating your privacy? It's only showing your files on your phone to you. The only way it could hurt your privacy is if you choose to let someone else look at that list on your phone.

Comment: @DanHulme Imagine you give your phone to your 8 year-old nephew to keep him busy, and you have some sensitive photos...

Comment: That's not a privacy violation, that's just you sharing some stuff you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is Clearing data in **App info** of **My Files**, After a few years using this phone, I think this is the only solution.

Slow way: **Settings -> Application manager -> All -> My Files -> Clear data**.

[image: Settings -> Application manager -> All -> My Files]

[image: IMG:]

Quick way: you can quickly open **App info** of **My Files** by holding the **My Files** app then drag it into the **App info**

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

Disable "Recent File"

## 1 Long route:

Settings -> Application manager (or Apps) -> All -> My Files -> App Info -> **"the Gear"** **(immediately below the three dots bar)** -> Customize My files home -> Disable "Recent files"

=> in this route, the three dots bar leads to "Uninstall updates".

## 2 Shorter route  (You don't see the "Gear", because you clicked directly on "My Files"):

My Files -> The three dots bar -> Settings -> My files settings  -> Customize My files home -> Disable "Recent files"

## 3 You have better eyes than I do:

Settings -> Application manager (or Apps) -> All -> My Files ->  **"the Gear"** (located on the right of the name) -> Customize My files home -> Disable "Recent files"

## 4 The final stage (this is where you should arrive)

[image: Disable "recent files"]

Comment: Samsung just added this feature, my old phone doesn't have this Disable Recent File feature, maybe some of Samsung dev read this question, lol :D, Thanks for sharing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an LG Q7 to delete the files I went into file manager pushed the  three dotted settings button, and selected show hidden. and searched through internal storage, found most of the thumbnails and cache in the pictures. A little digging as well in Android and DCIM was looking for anything that had a period in the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

In fact it is possible to do so. You just need to remove the cache files from Gallery and My Files then it removes recently added folders from Gallery and recent files from My Files.

Comment: Actually, the solution is already in the question: Settings -> Application manager -> All -> My Files -> Clear data.
Note: that you can do it quickly with Holding the "My Files" app, drag it into the "App info" (I don't remember the exactly word is App info or not), then the app info page appear, in this page you can: Turn off the app, clear the app cache, data,... Thus you can Clear the app data in this page.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. How did it solve the issue? Where to find it? What are the steps to perform?

Answer (score -1):

Just open your files and tap the 3 dots in right upper corner, and select settings, then turn **Show recent files** off.

Comment: Don't know about that, but I never saw that option on my phone. Can you post the image?

Answer (score -1):

- Go to **Files**
- select the 3 dots on the upper right
- Pick **Settings** and you'll see the screen below
- Turn off **Show recent files**

[image]